# Error while deploying springboot app to ibm cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

Getting below error when trying to deploy an springboot app to ibm cloud, the same app is working fine on my local. I have a trial account on ibm cloud.
"**RuntimeError: Application can not be run by more than one container: JAR, java-main, unknown, liberty-20.0.0_3 "

Let me know what is wrong.

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: "deploy to cloud": Kubernetes, Cloud Foundry, VM, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy a war file instead of a jar.

In my case, I have a maven-based app and my packaging property is set to war:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Also, you need to mark your tomcat (or whatever container you are using) dependency as provided:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Basically you get this setup when choosing war packaging in the spring initializer site.